# React Native random white screens throughout debug and release app

Tags: reactjs-flux, react-native, reactjs-native

I've been working on a React Native app on an Android tablet for my current contract and it's now going through its Alpha phase.  For the most part it's working very well, it's responsive, performant, and mostly stable.

There's one issue that keeps occurring though which I'm having trouble tracking down.  It seems very random since I've seen it happen on nearly every screen in the app all at times.
When transitioning to a new screen, I just get a blank white screen.  Seems like the javascript just doesn't get loaded and the UI never loads.  This happens in both our debug dev versions, and our bundled release versions.

Some things to note about the architecture

Android 6.0
React 15.4.1
React Native 0.39
Flux 3.1.0

I know this isn't a lot to go on so I'm mostly looking for people that may have experienced this problem (that wasn't related to the development server issues) and what they had found as a cause in their app.  Hoping to get some suggestions of what to look at or possibly how to even troubleshoot what's causing this.

Oh one other thing, If I background the app when a white screen happens, then select the app from my running apps list, the screen loads just fine and I'm able to continue using the app as if nothing happened.

Sorry for the vagueness here but I'm really at a loss and looking for any kind of suggestions.
Thanks!

Comment: Share the code where you think the problem lives, if we cant see how you have implemented it we cant help you.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca Thanks for the response.  I don't have any idea where since it happens everywhere.  I am thinking my problem is memory related and it appears my app is running about of memory when this white screen happens.  Still running memory profiling tests to see what's going on.

Comment: What navigator are you using to handle what screen you are on?

Comment: Hey, I also had a similar issue on iOS. I thought it is related to memory and I had a reason for it. First the issue was happening on the device during login. I was ok on the simulator. Second while i log in the user, I do lots of cryptography in the background. I thought that during encryption I ran out of memory. However what solved it was just deleting a `flex: 1` line from the style file of my loader gif. My conclusion was ReactNative somehow stucks while rendering and just lets everything go and goes white.

Comment: @rmevans9 It's not using a 3rd party navigation library, the app is just setup to use the standard Navigator class from the ReactNative package.

Comment: @mustafailkersarac I'm glad you've pointed that out because I redid the styles on one screen that this issue was happening on and so far I have not had it happen on that screen since.  In refactoring the styles I removed all of the nested flex: 1 declarations.  I wasn't sure that was the problem though since I began seeing the issue on most other screens.  I will explore this further and report back.  Thank you for sharing the info!

Comment: I hope that you can solve the mystery.